# Drill "VALIDATION ERROR: A table or view with given name already exists in schema" for empty directory

Tags: apache-drill

After upgrading drill on our cluster to drill-1.12.0-mapr, testing our daily ETL scripts (which all use drill for converting parquet files to tsv), a validation error ("*table or view with given name already exists*") is always thrown when trying to run a `CREATE TABLE` statement on some *empty* directories in a writable workspace.

```
[Error Id: 6ea46737-8b6a-4887-a671-4bddbea02476 on mapr002.ucera.local:31010]
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillCursor.nextRowInternally(DrillCursor.java:489)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillCursor.loadInitialSchema(DrillCursor.java:561)
:
:
:
Caused by: org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: A table or view with given name [/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv] already exists in schema [dfs.etl_internal]
```

After some brief debugging, I see that the FS directory in question under the specified dfs.etl_interal workspace (ie. /internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv) *is in fact empty*, yet still throwing these errors.

Looking for the error ID in the drillbit.log file in the associated node in the error message above, we see

```
2018-12-04 10:13:25,285 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman - Query text for query id 23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae: create table dfs.etl_internal.`/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv` as 
select <a bunch of fields>
from dfs.etl_internal.`/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/parquet`
2018-12-04 10:13:25,406 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.exec.store.dfs.FileSelection - FileSelection.getStatuses() took 0 ms, numFiles: 1
2018-12-04 10:13:25,408 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.exec.store.dfs.FileSelection - FileSelection.getStatuses() took 0 ms, numFiles: 1
2018-12-04 10:13:25,893 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.exec.store.dfs.FileSelection - FileSelection.getStatuses() took 0 ms, numFiles: 1
2018-12-04 10:13:25,894 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.exec.store.dfs.FileSelection - FileSelection.getStatuses() took 0 ms, numFiles: 1
2018-12-04 10:13:25,898 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.exec.store.dfs.FileSelection - FileSelection.getStatuses() took 0 ms, numFiles: 1
2018-12-04 10:13:25,898 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.exec.store.dfs.FileSelection - FileSelection.getStatuses() took 0 ms, numFiles: 1
2018-12-04 10:13:25,905 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.a.d.e.p.s.h.CreateTableHandler - User Error Occurred: A table or view with given name [/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv] already exists in schema [dfs.etl_internal]
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: VALIDATION ERROR: A table or view with given name [/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv] already exists in schema [dfs.etl_internal]


[Error Id: 45177abc-7e9f-4678-959f-f9e0e38bc564 ]
    at org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException$Builder.build(UserException.java:586) ~[drill-common-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.CreateTableHandler.checkTableCreationPossibility(CreateTableHandler.java:326) [drill-java-exec-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.handlers.CreateTableHandler.getPlan(CreateTableHandler.java:90) [drill-java-exec-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan(DrillSqlWorker.java:131) [drill-java-exec-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan(DrillSqlWorker.java:79) [drill-java-exec-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL(Foreman.java:567) [drill-java-exec-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run(Foreman.java:264) [drill-java-exec-1.12.0-mapr.jar:1.12.0-mapr]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
2018-12-04 10:13:25,924 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.work.WorkManager - Waiting for 0 queries to complete before shutting down
2018-12-04 10:13:25,924 [23f92019-db56-862f-e7b9-cd51b3e174ae:foreman] INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.work.WorkManager - Waiting for 0 running fragments to complete before shutting down
```

This error occurs even when using `DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] <workspace>.<table path name>` before the `CREATE TABLE` statement. Furthermore, the configurations for the dfs workspace itself does not appear to be changed from before upgrading to drill-1.12, see below:

```
:
:
"workspaces": {
"root": {
"location": "/",
"writable": false,
"defaultInputFormat": null,
"allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
},
"tmp": {
"location": "/tmp",
"writable": true,
"defaultInputFormat": null,
"allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
},
"etl_internal": {
"location": "/etl/internal",
"writable": true,
"defaultInputFormat": null,
"allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
}
},
:
:
```

Note that the full process in question is intended to `mv` the directory contents every day and `CREATE TABLE` with new data from current day (in case that makes a difference) and this process had been working fine when we were using drill-1.11.

More debugging information:

Simply deleting the .../tsv endpoint folder and relying on drill to make the directory during the CREATE TABLE statement does not work. Throws the unsurprising error

```
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Table [/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv] not found
[Error Id: 02e7c088-9162-4731-9fa8-85dfd39e1dec on mapr001.ucera.local:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

Ie. drill does not appear to be automatically creating the table.
Undoing these changes and rerunning to get the original error, we can examine the location via the sqlline interpreter interface. Doing so, we see

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=mapr001:5181,mapr002:5181,ma> describe dfs.etl_internal.`/internal_etl/project/version-2/stages/storage/ACCOUNT/tsv`;
+--------------+------------+--------------+
| COLUMN_NAME  | DATA_TYPE  | IS_NULLABLE  |
+--------------+------------+--------------+
+--------------+------------+--------------+
No rows selected (1.791 seconds)
```

So it sees something there, but only when *I make it myself*, which is like a catch-22 given that the original error is *complaining that something is already there*.

If anyone with more experience using drill knows what could be happening here, any opinions or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have made some mistake in the process of updating Drill version on your MapR cluster.

Please see this doc for more info: http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Upgrading+to+the+Latest+Version+of+Drill

or the last docs in case you are using the latest MapR Core version:
https://mapr.com/docs/home/UpgradeGuide/PreupgradeStepsDrill.html?hl=drill%2Cupgrade

https://mapr.com/docs/home/UpgradeGuide/PostUpgradeStepsDrill.html?hl=drill%2Cupgrade

`DROP TABLE` for Drill schemaless tables works fine. See more info about Drill schemaless tables (empty directories):
https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-sources-and-file-formats-introduction/#schemaless-tables

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: restarted the drillbits on the nodes and everything appears to be working now.

What was done to get drill to run the CTAS statement without error was:

1. Restart the drill services from the MapR MCS. This was done purely based
   on a hunch due to the hanging-drill-1.11-processes issue encountered
   earlier where after upgrading from drill-1.11 to drill-1.12, had problem where needed to manually go to each node, `jps` to see that drillbit 1.11 was still running, and `kill -9 <pid of 1.11 drillbit>`, and restart the drillbits to get 1.12 working. Not sure how much this helped,
   but documenting as it was the only change made in the process of
   debugging that was not undone before running
   the the changes that ultimately appear to have now resolved the
   error.
2. Changed the drill-using scripts to delete the target folder (`hadoop fs -rm -r /hdfs/path/to/folder`) of the CTAS statement after running some necessary processes on it and then letting the CTAS statement re-create it itself (even though as previously mentioned in original post, tried this earlier and received "Table not found" errors in a weird catch-22 situation (thus my thinking that restarting the drill services may have contributed)).

I know that just restarting the services may not be the best most informative answer, but that's what appeared to work here. If anyone as any more information or thoughts to add based on the solution description above do please leave a comment.